# Scroll DIV content instead of browser window

Tags: html, css, position

I created a modal window which has a Header, Body and Footer.

Instead of scrolling the browser window I need to scroll the Modal's Body.

Note that the Modal's Header and Footer should be fixed, e.g., not scroll.

How can I do this?

```css
div.cover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;  
}

div.modal {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 10% auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 400;
}

div.header, div.body, div.footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

div.body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear:before, .clear:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
} 

.clear:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor aliquet orci sit amet fringilla. Duis a ligula consequat, ornare elit eu, tincidunt turpis. 
</p>
<p>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. 
</p>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header clear">
      <p>Header</p>
      <a href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      Body<br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. 
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the updated example.

Header and Footer - Set to `position:absolute;`

```css
.cover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.modal {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10% auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 60vh;
  max-height: 60vh;
  position: relative !important;
}

.scrollView {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: calc(60vh - 100px);
  margin: 50px 0;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 800;
}

div.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 900;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header div {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

div.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor aliquet orci sit amet fringilla. Duis a ligula consequat, ornare elit eu, tincidunt turpis.
</p>
<p>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor.
</p>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header">
      <div>Header</div>
      <div><a href="#">Close</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollView">
      <div class="body">
        Body<br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor. Body
        <br><br>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor.
        <br><br> LAST LINE OF BODY
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need the modal's Header and Footer to be fixed

Comment: I am having a problem with your code. See the code update on my question. On the header I have a Title aligned left and an Anchor aligned right using floats and I am applying a padding to the header. Is there a way to keep using these CSS properties to keep that content layout?

Comment: So you just want the Close button on the right and Header to the left, right? I just did that to make it look better :)

Comment: Why removing the code line "border: solid 1px blue;" from modal breaks your code? It seems the body gets behind the header and the footer. I would like to now have the border but when I do that something strange happens.

Comment: please check the update, had to manipulate the container which handles the scroll.

Comment: Thank your for the help ... It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do. First set body overflow when your modal is open:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden; // inherit when modal is closed.
}
```

This will ensure that your content "behind" will not move with the scroll.

Secondly, you need to ensure the wrapper around your modal permits overflow scroll.

```
.modal-content-wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        ....
}
```